# I want to increase Specflow codedui's test timeout to greater than 30 minutes. How do I do this?

Tags: bdd, coded-ui-tests, specflow

I am using Specflow.codedui and I was wondering if you can set the timeout greater than 30 minutes. In Codedui you can use the Timeout Attribute. I tried using that on the hooks for Specflow but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Coded UI timeouts can also be specified via the `.testsettings` file. Do not know whether Specflow impacts on that.

Comment: I tried that but Specflow ignores them.